# A bug In Stack Exchange Data Query for How Unsung Am I

Tags: discussion, bug, data-explorer

I was surfing through the *How Unsung Am I* data queries, because I felt I would receive that soon. But one of the famous query by [Martijn Pieters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) showed that I had to go a long way to get that. But last day, I recieved it, but still the query shows I am not eligible.
So I compared it with another working query and I found *zero difference* between them. The only difference between [Martijn's Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/197953/how-unsung-am-i?UserId=13062813) and [My Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1228150/how-unsung-am-i-fixed-ver-includes?UserId=13062813) is that he used `count(a.Id)` while I used `count(a.Score)`. But you'll see that both give the same number, if you use both of them in the same query. But the query for my account, shows diffrent answers for the different queries.

(The queries include the answer with my user_id)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though the [SEDE homepage](https://data.stackexchange.com/) says it's updated 1 hour ago, this isn't true for the largest databases, including Stack Overflow. You have to wait a little bit longer (around noon UTC) before everything is refreshed. The query results will then more closely match the actual situation, though if you got new accepted answers earlier today, they still might not be reflected in the data.

Comment: To confirm: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1228802

Comment: Or this one: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1228803

Comment: @Glorfindel But the query results for my account is the same in martjin's query for 1 week almost, while my query did show variation :)